# Custom Navigation Bar across application

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-bar

I'm interested in an app that customizes the Android NavigationBar across all my applications. The same way that, *i.e.* [NavBar Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.damianpiwowarski.navbarapps) does it.

This far, I found two possibilities, but it doesn't fit exactly what I'm looking for:

**SystemBarTint library** ([here](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint))
It only works if you set your app to translucent, and display a background "tint" behind the NavigationBar.

**setNavigationBarColor(int color) ([here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setNavigationBarColor(int)))**
You can only use a color (and not a drawable) for the NavigationBar.

I want do an app that is always running and can set a drawable instead of the black color of the NavigationBar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out a way to customize the `NavigationBar` in (almost) all apps. (following [this](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics))

Using this permission:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Then I created a Service that calls:

```java
WindowManager.addView(View v, LayoutParams p)
```

And my MainActivity starts this Service.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the status/navigation bars color on all apps unless you are a rooted user and your custom rom / custom launcher supports this.

You can only change this inside you own application with any of the links you provided. But this will not extend to the rest of the device apps.

If the case is inside your own app you can do this by using setNavigationBarColor for the nacigation bar and the material design library for the status bar (set the secondaryColor on the material design.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so now my question is. How does [NavBar Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.damianpiwowarski.navbarapps&hl=pl) do that? I tried it on my phone, the app ask you for an Accessibility permission and then can change the Navbar color dependening on which app you launch. (With some fancy animation too...)

Comment: I think they do this trought the accesibility features That allow you to writer over the screen. Just like the facebook bubble work for the chatting app. They put this as an overlay on the phone.

Comment: if you see the app permissions it includes draw over other apps. So yeah, you need to do that

Comment: Link here http://qaoverflow.com/question/draw-over-navigation-bar-and-other-apps-on-android-version-5/ hope this will get you started

Comment: Thank you for everything, I will take a look !

Comment: It's possible to do it. You can check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40465413/4640003) .